# Как в Linux получить информацию о клиентском процессе по дескриптору окна X11?

Tags: linux, c, x11

Нужен надёжный способ программно получить какую-либо информацию о клиентском процессе, создавшем окно средствами X11. Так как процесс может быть каким угодно, свойства окна _NET_WM_PID, _NET_WM_NAME и т.п. не всегда бывают установлены. Интересует любая информация, позволяющая идентифицировать процесс. Не ставится требование использовать только механизмы X11. 
 Для упрощения предположим, что клиентский процесс выполняется на той же машине, что и сервер.

Comment: убрал второй вопрос, не имеющий отношения к первому: несвязанные вопросы здесь принято задавать отдельно.

Comment: *не всегда бывают установлены* — совершенно верно. захотел x-клиент — добавил свойство _NET_WM_PID, не захотел — не добавил. это ж *x window system*, а не дос какой-нибудь: тут работает клиент-серверная парадигма. и владельцем ресурсов (например, тех же окон) является **сервер**, а не клиент.

Comment: Александр, я это понимаю, но может быть существует другой путь выйти на процесс-владелец окна?

Comment: pid **владельца окна** вычислить очень просто: `$ pgrep X`.

Comment: Александр, я оценил вашу иронию, но я имел в виду процесс на стороне клиента. Возможно, это будет и не pid, а, к примеру,  дескриптор клиентского подключения. Нужна хоть какая-то зацепка.

Comment: я абсолютно серьёзен: x-протокол — это **сетевой** клиент-сервеный протокол. владелец окон и вот этого всего — сервер. клиентские процессы могут выполняться как тем же самым процессором, что и сервер, так и процессором, физически находящимся на другой стороне земнго шара. вы не в том месте ищете то, что вам нужно (да и вообще в вопросе об этом умолчали).

Comment: Замечание принимаю, исправляю заголовок.
По факту, меня интересует именно **клиентский** процесс. Упростим задачу: предположим, что он выполняется там же, где и сервер.

Comment: а с точки зрения x-протокола не имеет значения, где именно выполняется клиентский процесс: сервер обязан работать абсолютно одинаково. потому вопрос о «pid процесса» в рамках x-протокола полностью лишён смысла. // позвольте дать рекомендацию: решайте ту задачу, которая перед вами стоит, а не другую, которая, [как вам кажется, имеет какое-то отношение к первой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576). // p.s. иллюстрация: «как узнать pid браузера, подключившегося к моему http-серверу?». так понятней?

Comment: посмотрите на `xkill` он находит клиентский процесс

Comment: @eri xkill делает `XKillClient()` чнрнз API X'ов.

Comment: в расширении Xres и соответственно в libXres 1.2+ есть `XResQueryClientIds()`/`XResGetClientPid()`. Документации я к ним не нашёл, так что предлагаю обратиться к хедерам/исходникам... Если ответ в стиле «ты не должен этого хотеть» не устраивает, то думаю стоит копать в эту сторону...

Comment: @eri, Я обнаружил, что XKillClient делает запрос к серверу, то есть дальнейшее расследование надо вести на стороне сервера. Я подозреваю, что сервер просто-напросто закрывает соединение с клиентом, но в любом случае, там в каком-то виде должно храниться соответствие между окном и соединением. Будем искать.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо, я подозревал, что искомые функции есть в одном из расширений. Если не удастся с Xres, видимо придётся создавать собственное расширение X11.

Answer (score 0):

Обнаружил следующий вариант доработки X-сервера:

> Hello xorg-devel,
>
> I've been working on a window manager which utilizes the _NET_WM_PID
>   property of windows.  There are some applications I use which don't
>   set this correctly (xpdf for example).
>
> Most of the time I'm running local clients connected via unix domain
>   sockets.  Upon investigation I found Xorg already inquires as to the
>   unix credentials of such clients, which includes the client pid.
>
> Attached is a patch I developed which sets _NET_WM_PID for toplevel
>   windows using the already retrieved pid.  It was developed and tested
>   against xorg-server-1.12.4-6+deb7u2 from Debian 7.
>
> I'm not an experienced Xorg hacker, so maybe this isn't acceptable or
>   not the best way to do it.  It improves my use case by enabling my
>   window manager to know the PID of uncooperative local clients.
>
> Please CC me with any replies since I'm not subscribed.
>
> Thanks, Vito Caputo
>   -------------- next part --------------
>   --- xorg-server-1.12.4/dix/window.c   2012-05-17 10:09:02.000000000 -0700
>   +++ xorg-server-1.12.4.hacked/dix/window.c    2014-06-04 18:54:33.570855708 -0700 @@ -840,6 +840,20 @@

```
>          event.u.createNotify.override = pWin->overrideRedirect;
>          DeliverEvents(pParent, &event, 1, NullWindow);
>      }
> +
> +    if (pScreen->root == pParent) {
> +        /* top-level windows with local connections can reliably get _NET_WM_PID set by the server */
> +        LocalClientCredRec *lcc;
> +        if (GetLocalClientCreds(client, &lcc) != -1)
> +            if (lcc->fieldsSet & LCC_PID_SET) {
> +                Atom prop;
> +
> +                prop = MakeAtom("_NET_WM_PID", strlen("_NET_WM_PID"), TRUE);
> +                dixChangeWindowProperty(client, pWin, prop,
> +                                        XA_CARDINAL, 32, PropModeReplace,
> +                                        1, &lcc->pid, FALSE);
> +            }
> +    }
>      return pWin;  }
```

> [1]: https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2014-June/042840.html

Возможно, в моём случае это одно из решений проблемы (но нужно будет пересобрать X-сервер).